# Is there a point indexing a database column that does not have many different values?

Tags: database

For example suppose I have a column TYPE which only takes a few values.  I have queries such as

```
WHERE TYPE=...
```

Will indexing this column provide any improvement in performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a column's selectivity is very low (i.e. there are not many different values) then a query optimizer is unlikely to utilise an index on that column.

But, say you had a `Active` column (or other column with few distinct values), and the majority of records were active and just a few inactive (i.e. `Active` equal to `false`),  then a query with criteria `WHERE Active = False` might use an index on the `Active` column. [For SQL Server, the cutoff point is approximately 10% of the rows]

There are also other heuristics at play in multiple column indexes (and depends on your RDBMS)

For instance: [SQL Server Indexing: Using a Low-Selectivity BIT Column First Can Be the Best Strategy](http://sqlcat.com/technicalnotes/archive/2011/01/31/sql-server-indexing-using-a-low-selectivity-bit-column-first-can-be-the-best-strategy.aspx) (Thanks, Damien)

SQL Server 2008 onwards, has the ability to create ['Filtered Indexes'](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) for subsets of data:

> When a column only has a small number
>   of relevant values for queries, you
>   can create a filtered index on the
>   subset of values. For example, when
>   the values in a column are mostly NULL
>   and the query selects only from the
>   non-NULL values, you can create a
>   filtered index for the non-NULL data
>   rows. The resulting index will be
>   smaller and cost less to maintain than
>   a full-table nonclustered index
>   defined on the same key columns.

Comment: Decent [article](http://sqlcat.com/technicalnotes/archive/2011/01/31/sql-server-indexing-using-a-low-selectivity-bit-column-first-can-be-the-best-strategy.aspx) about the somewhat related topic of having a column with low selectivity *first* in a multi-column index.